# Zerobrane debug on Corona SDK

Tags: zerobrane

I try to debug with Zerobrane , code for Corona SDK, but when I press the button to start the debug, popups all the time a window saying that main.lua is used from other programs. There is no other program using the main.lua

When i press the button then the corona simulator starts and this is using the main.lua . When I kill the corona simulator the popup windows disappear.

Any other experienced this?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There was a [fix for the files not closed](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/commit/fe764476bd38df1be90935ab8097d70a53bb12c9), which may be related to this issue. You can try with the [current master branch version](https://github.com/pkulchenko/ZeroBraneStudio/archive/master.zip) to see if it fixes the problem.